# problem with ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Running:

```
phablet-flash ubuntu-system --no-backup
```

I get the following message:

```
INFO:phablet-flash:Device detected as C1505

ERROR:phablet-flash:Unsupported device, autodetect fails device
```

can you help me ?
thanks

Comment: what device are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Are you using an xperia?
 I see that C1505 might be their code.
It's only supported for Nexus phones right now. To force the Nexus 4 (mako) install try this:

`sudo phablet-flash ubuntu-system --no-backup -d mako`

Make sure you don't mind bricking this phone if it's not a Nexus 4.